# Toggle open/close accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to make my accordion menu toggle open/close using the same button.

At the moment it just opens and  I cannot close it.

My code is below, alternatively here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndczc728/5/

```
//Accordion
(function($) {

var allPanels = $('ul.sub-level').hide();

$('.click-me').click(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    $target =  $this.next();

    if(!$target.hasClass('active')){
        allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
        $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
    }

    return false;
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply... Just add the else statement to your If statement:

```
//Accordion
(function($) {

    var allPanels = $('ul.sub-level').hide();

    $('.click-me').click(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $target =  $this.next();

      if(!$target.hasClass('active')){
         allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
         $target.addClass('active').slideDown(); 
      }
      else
      {
         allPanels.removeClass('active').slideUp();
      }

    return false;
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ndczc728/15/

Comment: What an idiot I am!! Thanks! Its always the simplest of things isn't?!

Comment: @egr103 Hey, it happens to the best of us.  Glad to help! :)

Comment: @egr103 Updated to put back in your slide up in the IF section, as it shouldn't have been removed.  Cause it is used to slide up all other active panels when you click a new one. (Since I am assuming that is what you wanted based on your code)

Answer (score 0):

You never toggled it back up.

http://jsfiddle.net/ndczc728/8/

```
    if(!$target.hasClass('active')){
         $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
      }
      else
      {
         $target.removeClass('active').slideUp();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple fix that keeps track of counts:

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/ndczc728/14/)

```
(function ($) {
    $('ul.sub-level').hide();
    var c = 1;
    $('.click-me').click(function () {
        c++ % 2 == 0 ? $('ul.sub-level').slideUp() : $(this).next().slideDown();
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```